# Back to the previous view in UINavigationViewController is not animated when pressed on the back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

UITabBarController is the root in may application. 
The root of each tab is different UINavigationViewController on which I am pushing UITableViewController's.

The problem is that when I press on the back button the navigation bar animates, but the previous table view appears instantly without animation. Neither UITableViewController nor UINavigationViewController is sub-classed and I have no any custom code for pop functionality.

Some time ago, when I was working on the other iOS application, I had not such problem.
The only difference is that now I am working with XCode 4 and iOS 5 SDK.

I have spent a lot to find the answer but haven't found anything similar.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this myself for quite a while. In my case the problem ended up being me accidentally overriding viewDidAppear and not calling [super viewDidAppear:animated] in my custom UITabBarController class.

Once I got rid of that the issue finally went away.

Comment: Thanks, for the response.
I have finally found the problem:
I have set accidentally my root navigation view to be subview of the window [self.window addSubview:rootController.view]; rather than
self.window.rootViewController = rootController;
Once I have fixed it the problem gone:)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the problem:
I have set accidentally my root view to be subview of the window

```
[self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
```

rather than

```
self.window.rootViewController = rootController;
```

Once I have fixed it the problem gone:)

Answer (score 0):

Do not do any UI updation task in background thread or dispatch asyncq  background queue in ios 7 ,if you are doing any ui related task then do it in main queue.Eg.

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                       {
                       //update ui
                       }
```

This will solve navigation controller animation related issue.